# Schema hasn't been registred for model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, passport.js

i know the question already has been asking, but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong on my code, in my '/' when i start the app the router executes my index.js file that has the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Loja = require('../models/lojas');

router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
 console.log('Time: ', Date());
 console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
 console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
 next(); //passa a solicitação para a próxima função de middleware na pilha
});

//get all contacts with specific filter
router.post('/registo',function(req,res){
  var loja = new Loja();

  loja.name = req.body.name;
  loja.email = req.body.email;

  loja.setPassword(req.body.password);

  loja.save(function(err){
      var token;
      token = loja.generateJwt;
      res.status(200);
      res.json({
          "token": token
      });
  });

});
```

**my app.js looks like following:**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-Parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
require('./config/passport');
var app = express();


var dbName = 'LojasDB';
var connectionString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017' + dbName;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(connectionString);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(passport.initialize());


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-MethodOverride,Content-Type, Accept');
next();
});

app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));

app.listen(8080,function(){
    console.log("listen on port 8080");
})
```

basicly i have a model called loja, that i want to use to authenticate, so i used passport for the first time to do this, but somehow i get a error that the schema hasn't been registred for that model, my model looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var lojasSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});

lojasSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
  var expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    email: this.email,
    name: this.name,
    exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
  }, "12345"); // DO NOT KEEP YOUR SECRET IN THE CODE!
};

lojasSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

lojasSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
  return this.hash === hash;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Loja',lojasSchema);
```

so i am exporting the model here, so in my router index.js i require it like this:

```
var Loja = require('../models/lojas');
```

Comment: Did you create/register the model according to the Mongoose documentation ? => http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html ..... var lojas = mongoose.model('Lojas', lojasSchema);  ... I think it's necessary to register the Model.

Comment: yep i have it in my model last line

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
var lojasSchema = mongoose.Schema({
```

should be:

```
var lojasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
```

Comment: you are right, i change it, but it continues to fail with the same error, :S

Comment: Also as @mrtaz stated you are not exporting your **route** in your index.js file: add `module.exports = router;` to the end of *index.js* file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are exporting your routes from that index.js file as I see they are separate from your app.js file. You need to require your Mongoose Models in your app.js file. So add something like this in your app.js.

`var Loja = require('../models/lojas');`

Comment: i am doing that to :S, have no idea about the error, i will comit it to github, can you take a look?

Comment: You are exporting your routes? Yeah I can check it out.

Comment: Ahh okay, in your passport.js file change this.  `var Loja = mongoose.model('Loja');` to `var Loja = require('../models/lojas.js')`

Comment: thank you very much post that as a answer so i can accept it :)